# Three subfigures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to add generate three subfigures in latex like the attached photo.

[image]

My code is

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.66\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figA.eps}
\caption{(a)}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{figB.jpg}
\caption{(b)}
\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{figC.jpg}
\caption{(c)}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{title...}
\label{fig:subbbb}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that I am getting three separate figures, I just need the letter a, b, and c next to each figure instead of Figure (a), Figure (b), and Figure (c).

Comment: just use <blank line>`(a)` not `\caption{{a)}`

Comment: location of (a) and (c) was good but (b) is far all the way to the right of the page! @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Will you need to be able to create cross-references to one or more of the subfigures?

Comment: yes I need to create cross-references to each of the subfigures @Mico